# Json Parsing Swift 3 Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, parsing, alamofire

I am new at Swift 3 and I got problems with getting Json return then sending request. I am trying to send a post request to the server with parameters username and password and get a response with Json with information, but I haven't been able to get the data to return.

Output:

> error: NSURLErrorDomain: -1003
>       status code: 200, headers 
>           Connection = close;
>           "Content-Type" = "application/json";
>           "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity

request on Android looks like:

```
            "{\n" +
            "    \"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\",\n" +
            "    \"id\": \"1\",\n" +
            "    \"method\": \"call\",\n" +
            "    \"params\": [\n" +
            "        \"" + LOGIN_TOKEN + "\",\n" +
            "        \"session\",\n" +
            "        \"login\",\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"username\": \"" + userName + "\",\n" +
            "            \"password\": \"" + password + "\"\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    ]\n" +
            "}";
```

this is what I should send to request:

```
"{ \"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"id\": 1, \"method\": \"call\", \"params\": [ \"00000000000000000000000000000000\", \"session\", \"login\", { \"username\": \"root\", \"password\": \"admin01\"  } ] }"
```

This is my code:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   var userName = "root"
   var password = "admin01"
   //var LOGIN_TOKEN = 0000000000000000

    let jsonObject: [String: Any] =
        ["jsonrpc" : 2.0,
         "id": 1,
         "method": "call",
         "params": [ "00000000000000",
                     "session",
                     "login",
                     [ "username": userName,
                       "password": password]],
         ]

    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: .prettyPrinted)
        // here "jsonData" is the dictionary encoded in JSON data

        let decoded = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
        // here "decoded" is of type `Any`, decoded from JSON data

        // you can now cast it with the right type
        if let dictFromJSON = decoded as? [String:String] {
            // use dictFromJSON
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    Alamofire.request("http://192.168.1.1/ubus", method: .post, parameters: jsonObject, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response)
            //to get status code
            if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
                switch(status){
                case 201:
                    print("example success")
                default:
                    print("error with response status: \(status)")
                }
            }
            //to get JSON return value
            if let result = response.result.value {
                let JSON = result as! NSDictionary
                print(JSON)
            }

    }

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: try using SwiftyJSON https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON object seems to be invalid

There are really helpful JSON validators that are free. One that comes to mind is http://jsonlint.com

I think, from what I can interpret by the code you posted, that you want your jsonObject to look something like this, which is a valid JSON:

```
[
    {
    "jsonrpc": 2.0,
    "id": 1,
    "method": "call",
    "params": ["00000000000000", "session", "login"],
    "username": username,
    "password": password
    }
]
```

I assume the `username` and `password` variables are strings you have already assigned?

Comment: I got some errors. After "jsonrpc" need ; and any type cant be used with arrays, I got request onAndroid studio and its working perfectly.

Comment: @GediminasUrbonas - That's because it's `JSON` code, and you're trying to make it a `Swift` object. You should look into creating a `JSON` file with the above code, and then learn how to convert `JSON` to `Data`. You can't just cast `JSON` code as `Swift Data`, it has to be converted somehow.